# RxJs: Emit each value of a sequence separately

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

RxJs, Typescript 1.8 and Angular2.

I have a function which returns an Observable.  The Observable calls a web API, which returns a sequence of objects.  Here is my actual code:

```
  getClients(): Observable<IClient[]> {
    return this.backendService.get(`tracker/clients`)
      .map((resp: {}[]) => { return _.map(resp, createClientFromJson)})
      .map((clients: IClient[]) => {
        this.logger.debug(`Created ${clients.length} Clients from reply`);
        return clients;
      });
  }
```

The call to `backendService.get()` ultimately calls `http.get()`, which returns an `Observable`.

And my code which consumes the events from the Observable:

```
  loadClients() {
    this.getClients().subscribe((clients: IClient[]): void => {
      this.clients = this.clients.concat(clients);
      this.logger.debug(`Got ${clients.length} clients, now have ${this.clients.length}.`);
    })
  }
```

This all works.  However my Observable emits a single time - with a sequence of N elements.  If the web API returns a sequence of 20 items, only 1 event will be emitted to `loadClients()`.

How can I make it so that each item in the sequence is emitted by itself, instead of emitting the entire sequence all at once?

In some parts of my program, I need the entire sequence.  In others I need to look for one particular element that matches some criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
this.getClients().flatMap(clients => Observable.from(clients)).subscribe(client => {
   // do something with client
})
```

Comment: Will this result in an `Observable<IClient>` or an `Observable<Observable<IClient>>`?  I ask because I tried something along these lines, but it resulted in an observable-of-observable, which was difficult to deal with.

Comment: Just do `flatMap(clients => clients)`

Comment: I ended up going with `flatMap(clients => clients)`, rather than `Observable.from(...)`

Comment: @John, it would result in nested observable if you would use `map` instead of `flatMap` a.k.a `concatMap`. It has ability of flattering inner observables to values

Answer (score 2):

```
this.getClients().switch(v => v).subscribe(clients => {
  // your original code 
});
```

Comment: This is great to know about, but in my use case I'm implementing a function `getEachClient()` which should emit each `IClient` by itself.  Using `switch` will (seem to) result in each `IClient` being emitted in it's own 1-element sequence.  Using `flatMap` seems like a more natural fit to my use case.